# how to iterate installation in a row

Tags: yum, for

I need a script in order to, giving a packages list as arguments, the script performs the installation of the packages in one row. For example launching the script in this way:

```
script package1 package2 package3
```

it performs the installation in this way:

```
yum -y install package1 package2 package3
```

Clearly I'm in a situation in which I can't install them directly but I need to use a script.
How could I do? This way install the packages in different rows and is not what I need.

```
for pkg in "$@"
do
    yum -y install "$pkg"
done
```

Comment: `yum -y install $*` perhaps? But why do it in a script at all?

Comment: because the script will be execute by another program and the packages list given by the user

Comment: @Kusalananda: How could I do if the list must be given to yum command separated by commas? for example for RHSA: yum -y -v update --advisory=FIRST_RHSA,SECOND_RHSA. Do I have to work with array? Considering that the list is given separated by " " space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable thing to do in your script:

```
yum -y install "$@"
```

`"$@"` will expand to the individually quoted command line arguments of the script itself, just like it would do in your `for`-loop. But instead of looping over the arguments, you pass them all to `yum -y install` in one go.

Comment: yes it runs and it's very easy. I obtained the same result pushing all the arguments in an array and the executing the installation with the array but your solution is the best. Thanks

Comment: How could I do if the list must be given to yum command separated by commas? for example for RHSA: `yum -y -v update --advisory=FIRST_RHSA,SECOND_RHSA`. Do I have to work with array?